# Node-Red - JSON Parsing Not Working

Tags: json, parsing, node-red

I am pulling data from the things network via MQTT. I am having trouble parsing the data and being able to see each part of the data in a separate variable.

[image: Node-Red Flow]

**This is the given output from the debug:**

```
{"payload":"Gc4FaAAAFwBoAA==","port":223,"counter":4527,"dev_eui":"00DEAD00BEEF0002","metadata":
[{"frequency":902.3,"datarate":"SF10BW125","codingrate":"4/5","gateway_timestamp":1299905004,"channel":0,"server_time":"2016-09-

03T18:40:46.106713105Z","rssi":-31,"lsnr":12.3,"rfchain":0,"crc":1,"modulation":
"LORA","gateway_eui":"1234567887654321","altitude":0,"longitude":0,"latitude":0}
]}
```

**The code in parsingJson:**

```
var data = JSON.parse(msg.payload);
msg.payload={};
msg.payload = data.metadata.rssi;
msg.payload = data.payload;
msg.payload = data.payload.split(1,3);

return msg;
```

Comment: Could you please post the error also?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: You assign three different things to msg.payload - only the last of those might have any effect. Anyway the content in msg.metadata is in a list, so to access the content of the first item in the list you need to index the list, like `msg.metadata[0].rssi`.

Answer (score 0):

First up, don't bother converting the string to JSON in the function node, there is a specific pre-installed standard node (named JSON node, this will convert strings to JSON or JSON to stings based on input) in the pallet that will do that for you.

Secondly your setting the `msg.payload` 3 times so you will only ever get the last part.

Thirdly `data.metadata` is an array so you need to specify which entry in the array you want to access, e.g. `data.metatdata[0].rssi`

You have nothing connected to the function output so what output are you expecting?

Comment: I am trying to take certain parts of the JSON and inserting them into a MySQL DB. I was hoping to assign certain parts to variables then calling the variables in the sql statement, but my first step was outputting the data. So if I want to output the port and the longitude, how would I do that?

Comment: It sounds like your going to need more step by step help than SO is suited for. You should ask this on the Node-RED forum where somebody can guide you through this. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/node-red